# Can DataNucleus Enhancer process classes that are in jar on a classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, datanucleus

There is Google App Engine Java project "A" that is based on a large portion of the classes from another Google App Engine Java "B" but not all of them.

For this all those classes from Project "B" are exported as Jar with source code that is included on class path of the project "A" among them few @Entity classes.

When running project "A" in local debug mode I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class UserAccount for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports specification
    at biz.daich.gwt.common.app.server.domain.services.UserAccountService.findOrCreateUserAccountByPrimaryEmail(UserAccountService.java:123)
    at biz.daich.gwt.common.app.server.domain.services.UserAccountService.getCurrentLogIn(UserAccountService.java:312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)......
```

This is makes sense as class UserAccount was not enhanced by the DataNucleus Enhancer as it is not in the list of files for enhancement.

How can I configure the Google Plugin/Google App Engine/DataNucleus Enhancer to do the bytecode enhancement on those classes as it does with classes that I select by pattern in the Eclipse  **Project Properties -> Google -> App Engine -> ORM** ?

Can it be done this way?

```
    If YES: How to define a pattern?

    If NO: How can I link few classes from another project, not even a whole package, in to the source tree of this project that will do the trick?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to update classes that are in a jar with new bytecode; apart from unjarring them, enhancing them, and rejarring them.

Comment: Is it possible to enhance them while building project B so that the project-B.jar used in project A already has enhanced bytecode?